# VBA to apply formulas depending on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new with VBA. I did another post asking how to apply different formulas based in (50+) different conditions, as I was using a IF formula but it was too long for a cell. Someone suggested that I should use VBA and macros.

I now have the VBA code with all the formulas/conditions, but I don't know how to make it dynamic. I tried with a loop, but it was applying the formulas based on the first row and not on the subsequents. For example in cell J2 the formula was based in condition O2 with data in cell I2. But in cell J3, was based in condition O3 but again with data from I2. I need the formula to work by row. Here's what I have:

```
Sub ApplyFormulasToCells()
    Dim conditionRange As Range
    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Dim resultRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Set the range for conditions, formulas, and result cells
    Set conditionRange = Range("O2:O9000") ' Assuming you have conditions in O2 to O9000
    Set formulaRange = Range("P2:P9000")   ' Assuming you have formulas in P2 to P9000
    Set resultRange = Range("J2:J9000")    ' Assuming you want results in J2 to J9000

    ' Loop through each row
    For i = 1 To conditionRange.Rows.Count
        Dim condition As String
        Dim formula As String

        ' Get the condition in the current row
        condition = Trim(conditionRange.Cells(i, 1).Value)

        ' Check if the condition is blank
        If condition = "" Then
            ' If blank, copy the information from the corresponding column in I
            resultRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = Range("I" & i + 1).Value
        Else
            ' Use a Select Case statement to check the condition and apply the corresponding formula
            Select Case condition
                Case "10TH"
                    formula = "=IF(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "1st and 3rd Friday of every month"
                    formula = "=IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-6),(I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+1+1*7-WEEKDAY((I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+8-6)))"
                Case "2ND 10TH 20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),2),AND(DAY(I2)>2,DAY(I2)<=10),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=20),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,2))"
                Case "16TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),16),DAY(I2)>16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,16))"
                Case "7TH"
                    formula = "=IF(DAY(I2)<=7,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),7),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,7))"
                Case "7TH 27TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=7,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),7),AND(DAY(I2)>7,DAY(I2)<=27),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),27),DAY(I2)>27,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,7))"
                Case "7TH 20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=7,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),7),AND(DAY(I2)>7,DAY(I2)<=20),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,7))"
                Case "20TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),AND(DAY(I2)>20,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,20))"
                Case "2nd and 4th weeks of the month on thursday"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),1)+14-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),1),15)+14,DAY(I2)>=16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,1)+14-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,1),15))"
                Case "10TH 20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=20),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "10TH 20TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=20),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),AND(DAY(I2)>20,DAY(I2)<=31),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "10TH 25TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "10TH 25TH Don't chase"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "1-15 to be paid on 20th 16-31 on the 5th"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "15TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),DAY(I2)>15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,15))"
                Case "13TH"
                    formula = "=IF(DAY(I2)<=13,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),13),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,13))"
                Case "15TH 25TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),AND(DAY(I2)>15,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,15))"
                Case "15TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),AND(DAY(I2)>15,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,15))"
                Case "15TH 31ST"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),AND(DAY(I2)>15,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,15))"
                Case "16TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),16),AND(DAY(I2)>16,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,16))"
                Case "18TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=18,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),18),DAY(I2)>18,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,18))"
                Case "18TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=18,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),18),AND(DAY(I2)>18,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,18))"
                Case "1ST"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=1,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),1),DAY(I2)>1,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,1))"
                Case "1ST 15TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=1,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),1),AND(DAY(I2)>1,DAY(I2)<=15),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),DAY(I2)>15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,1))"
                Case "1ST 16TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=1,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),1),AND(DAY(I2)>1,DAY(I2)<=16),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),16),DAY(I2)>16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,1))"
                Case "1st and 3rd Thursday of the month"
                    formula = "=IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+2*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),I2-DAY(I2)+1+2*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+4*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),I2-DAY(I2)+1+4*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),(I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+1+2*7-WEEKDAY((I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+8-5)))"
                Case "20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,20))"
                Case "20TH 31ST"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),AND(DAY(I2)>20,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,20))"
                Case "22ND"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=22,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),22),DAY(I2)>22,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,22))"
                Case "25TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,25))"
                Case "25TH NEVER CHASE THEM"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,25))"
                Case "27TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=27,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),27),DAY(I2)>27,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,27))"
                Case "28TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=28,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),28),DAY(I2)>28,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,28))"
                Case "2ND"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),2),DAY(I2)>2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,2))"
                Case "2ND 16TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),2),AND(DAY(I2)>2,DAY(I2)<=16),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),16),DAY(I2)>16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,2))"
                Case "2ND 17TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),2),AND(DAY(I2)>2,DAY(I2)<=17),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),17),DAY(I2)>17,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,2))"
                Case "2ND 18TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=2,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),2),AND(DAY(I2)>2,DAY(I2)<=18),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),18),DAY(I2)>18,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,2))"
                Case "30/31ST"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,30))"
                Case "45 DAYS AFTER 16th OF THE FOLLOWING MONTH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),16+45),DAY(I2)>16,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,16+45))"
                Case "30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,30))"
                Case "5TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),5),DAY(I2)>5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "5TH 15TH 25TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),5),AND(DAY(I2)>5,DAY(I2)<=15),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),AND(DAY(I2)>15,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "5TH 20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),5),AND(DAY(I2)>5,DAY(I2)<=20),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>20,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "5TH 25TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),5),AND(DAY(I2)>5,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "8TH 22ND"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=8,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),8),AND(DAY(I2)>8,DAY(I2)<=22),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),22),DAY(I2)>22,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,8))"
                Case "10TH 25TH Don't chase"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),DAY(I2)>25,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                Case "Mondays"
                    formula = "=IF(MOD(I2-1,7)>1,I2+1-MOD(I2-1,7)+7,I2+1-MOD(I2-1,7))"
                Case "inv until 15TH to be paid on 20TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),20),DAY(I2)>15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,20))"
                Case "Last Friday of the month"
                    formula = "=DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,0)+MOD(-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,0),2)-2,-7)"
                Case "Wednesdays"
                    formula = "=IF(MOD(I2-1,7)>3,I2+3-MOD(I2-1,7)+7,I2+3-MOD(I2-1,7))"
                Case "Thursdays"
                    formula = "=IF(MOD(I2-1,7)>4,I2+4-MOD(I2-1,7)+7,I2+4-MOD(I2-1,7))"
                Case "Fridays"
                    formula = "=IF(MOD(I2-1,7)>5,I2+5-MOD(I2-1,7)+7,I2+5-MOD(I2-1,7))"
                Case "1st and 3rd Wednesday of every month"
                    formula = "=IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-4),I2-DAY(I2)+1+1*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-4),IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-4),I2-DAY(I2)+1+3*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-4),(I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+1+1*7-WEEKDAY((I2+10)-DAY((I2+10))+8-4)))"
                Case "2nd and 4th Thursday of every month"
                    formula = "=IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+2*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),I2-DAY(I2)+1+2*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),IF(I2<I2-DAY(I2)+1+4*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),I2-DAY(I2)+1+4*7-WEEKDAY(I2-DAY(I2)+8-5),(I2+11)-DAY((I2+11))+1+2*7-WEEKDAY((I2+11)-DAY((I2+11))+8-5)))"
                Case "5TH 15TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=5,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),5),AND(DAY(I2)>5,DAY(I2)<=15),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),DAY(I2)>15,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,5))"
                Case "Tuesdays"
                    formula = "=IF(MOD(I2-1,7)>3,I2+2-MOD(I2-1,7)+7,I2+2-MOD(I2-1,7))"
                Case "26TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=26,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),26),DAY(I2)>26,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,26))"
                Case "10TH 15TH 25TH 30TH"
                    formula = "=IFS(DAY(I2)<=10,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),10),AND(DAY(I2)>10,DAY(I2)<=15),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),15),AND(DAY(I2)>15,DAY(I2)<=25),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),25),AND(DAY(I2)>25,DAY(I2)<=30),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),30),DAY(I2)>30,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,10))"
                ' Add more cases as needed for conditions 3 to 50
                Case "14TH"
                    formula = "=IF(DAY(I2)<=14,DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2),14),DATE(YEAR(I2),MONTH(I2)+1,14)),I2))"
                Case Else
                    ' Default case if no condition matches
                    formula = "NoFormula"
            End Select

            ' Apply the formula to the corresponding cell in the result range
            resultRange.Cells(i, 1).formula = formula
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Replace in all the formulas I2 with the expression you applied previously. `Range("I" & i + 1).Value`

Comment: If you don't want it to become super bombastic with replacing `I2` with `" & Range("I" & i+1).Value & "`, you can replace it with `R[1]C[-1]` (as long as it's only that one reference in the formulas, I think this is the case here) and then use `resultRange.Cells(i,1).FormulaR1C1 = formula`. Are you sure you want `i+1` btw? You mention *"copy the information from the corresponding column in I"* which would mean just `i`, no? If so, it's just `RC[-1]` instead of `R[1]C[-1]`